# Reading Data From a File Logic Error in C

Tags: c, xcode

I wrote the following function to read the data from a file containing a set of strings and floating point values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char Name[100];
    char Title;
    double Hours_Worked;
    double Pay_Rate;
    double Payment;
} Employee;

void Read_Records_From_File(FILE *Read_File, Employee *Payroll)
{
    int Index;
    char First_Name[100], Last_Name[100];
    
    Index = 0;
    
    while (!feof(Read_File))
    {
        fgets(Payroll[Index].Name, 100, Read_File);
        strtok(Payroll[Index].Name, "\n");
        
        fscanf(Read_File, "%c", &Payroll[Index].Title);
        
        fscanf(Read_File, "%lf", &Payroll[Index].Hours_Worked);
        fscanf(Read_File, "%lf", &Payroll[Index].Pay_Rate);
        
        printf("Name : %s", Payroll[Index].Name);
        printf("\nTitle : %c", Payroll[Index].Title);
        printf("\nHours Worked : %lf", Payroll[Index].Hours_Worked);
        printf("\nPay Rate : %lf", Payroll[Index].Pay_Rate);
        puts("\n");
        
        Index += 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *Read_File;
    Employee Payroll[100];
    
    Read_File = fopen("Payroll.txt", "r");
    
    Read_Records_From_File(Read_File, &Payroll);
}
```

File Contents

```
SurName1 FirstName1
B
40.0
12.0
SurName2 FirstName2
M
35.0
20.0
```

However when i run this program it gives me an odd output and I cant figure out why.

Output

```
Name : SurName1 FirstName1
Title : B
Hours Worked : 40.000000
Pay Rate : 12.000000

Name : 

Title : S
Hours Worked : 0.000000
Pay Rate : 0.000000

Name : urName2 FirstName2
Title : M
Hours Worked : 35.000000
Pay Rate : 20.000000

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I am not a 100% sure why but I suspect it has something to do with the use of `fgets` and `strtok`.

Just to be clear I know this can be done using `fscanf` but I dont want to do that because I am trying to learn to use `fgets`

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) and [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: You should also always check to be sure a file was opened before using the file pointer and check the return value from operations like `fgets` and `fscanf` so you can tell if they succeeded or not.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yep i get what your saying to check if the file is open but in this case i didnt because it is reading data from the file just not the way i intended for it to be. So i guess we can say that the file was opened without a problem. Also i do admit i forgot to close the file, but that shouldnt cause too much of an issue as far as i know

Comment: Visit the links I posted, specifically the one about scanf. That is your current problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, Sorry but im not sure i follow. So basically scanf and fgets leave a new line character and that is my problem right? But im using strtok to remove this new line character so i dont really gets what wrong. Sorry but im kinda new to C.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems:

- don't use `feof()`: it does not do what you think it does. Read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) .

  To detect the end of file, you should test the return value of `fgets()` and you should also test the return value of `fscanf()`.
- `fscanf()` leaves the trailing newline in the input stream after the `%c` and `%lf` conversions, hence `fgets()` will read an empty line at the beginning of the second iteration, the next `fscanf()` reads the first character of the name and the next 2 calls to `fscanf()` fail to convert a number, leaving the destination variables unchanged (and in this case uninitialized). Always test the return value of `fscanf()`: it returns the number of successful conversions.  Mixing calls to `fscanf()` and `fgets()` is tricky, skipping whitespace, including newlines must be done manually for `%c` and `%[`.
- there is no check for buffer overflow: if more than 100 records are available in the file, the (corrected) program would write beyond the end of the `Payroll` array.  You should pass the array length and check it in the function.
- `fopen()` failure is not tested
- the file is not closed

Here is a modified version using `fscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char Name[100];
    char Title;
    double Hours_Worked;
    double Pay_Rate;
    double Payment;
} Employee;

int Read_Records_From_File(FILE *Read_File, Employee *Payroll, int length)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        if (fscanf(Read_File, " %99[^\n] %c %lf %lf",
                   Payroll[index].Name,
                   &Payroll[index].Title,
                   &Payroll[index].Hours_Worked, 
                   &Payroll[index].Pay_Rate) != 4) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Name : %s\n", Payroll[index].Name);
        printf("Title : %c\n", Payroll[index].Title);
        printf("Hours Worked : %lf\n", Payroll[index].Hours_Worked);
        printf("Pay Rate : %lf\n\n", Payroll[index].Pay_Rate);
    }
    return index;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *Read_File;
    Employee Payroll[100];
    
    Read_File = fopen("Payroll.txt", "r");
    if (Read_File != NULL) {
        Read_Records_From_File(Read_File, &Payroll, 100);
        fclose(Read_File);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since you want to use `fgets()`, which allows for better error checking and recovery, here is an alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char Name[100];
    char Title;
    double Hours_Worked;
    double Pay_Rate;
    double Payment;
} Employee;

int Read_Records_From_File(FILE *Read_File, Employee *Payroll, int length)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        char buf[101];
        char *p;

        // read the name
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, Read_File))
            break;
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any
        strcpy(Payroll[index].Name, buf);

        // read the title
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, Read_File))
            break;
        Payroll[index].Title = *buf;

        // read the hours
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, Read_File))
            break;
        Payroll[index].Hours_Worked = strtod(buf, &p);
        if (p == buf)
            printf("invalid hours: %s\n", buf);

        // read the pay rate
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, Read_File))
            break;
        Payroll[index].Pay_Rate = strtod(buf, &p);
        if (p == buf)
            printf("invalid pay rate: %s\n", buf);

        printf("Name : %s\n", Payroll[index].Name);
        printf("Title : %c\n", Payroll[index].Title);
        printf("Hours Worked : %lf\n", Payroll[index].Hours_Worked);
        printf("Pay Rate : %lf\n\n", Payroll[index].Pay_Rate);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Quick Question, what does %99[^\n] do? in the if condition.  Because i thought fscanf stopped the moment a space was reached right? So how does it read in the whole name?

Comment: @TheRecon007: `%s` skips initial whitespace, then reads the characters and stops on white space. `%99[^\n]` reads up to 99 characters, stopping only on a newline character.  Always tell `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store for `%s` and `%[` to prevent buffer overflows.